# Django: is_valid() method is always return why?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm just practicing django and creating simple app that take user name and profile pic and then save it in database.is_valid() method is always return false when i do form validation.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import student,photo
from .forms import student_data
# Create your views here.
def my_data(request):
    check=0
    myform=student_data()
    if (request.method=="POST"):
        myform=student_data(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if (myform.is_valid()):
            stu_name=myform.cleaned_data['name']
            stu_image=myform.cleaned_data['image']
            d=photo.objects.filter(name=stu_name)
            myform.save()
            if not d:
                new_data=photo(image=stu_image,name=stu_name)
                photo.save(self=new_data)
            else:
                check=1
    else:
        myform=student_data
    return render(request,'show.html',{'student':stu_name,'check':check})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
#from .models import student

class student_data(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=20)
    image=forms.ImageField()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class photo(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table='photo'
```

html file for form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="form" action="/payment/show/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">Add Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form (since you both add data and files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you submit both data and files, the encoding type of the form should be `multipart/form-data`, so:

```
<form name="form" action="/payment/show/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Add Me</button>
</form>
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)
>   than to write hardcoded urls. It makes it easier to understand to what view you
>   are referring, if you later change the URL, the url resolution will change as
>   well, and it will encode the url values if necessary.

Comment: thank you it worked but save() method of form is not working after this changes why?

Comment: @ManinderSingh: it is a simple `Form`, not a `ModelForm`, hence unless you implemented a `save` yourself, it is not doing anything.